# Is it possible to generate a partial view on the click of a button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to generate a partial view when I click a certain button on my view and display it on a different view.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create a partial view on clicking button for that you can add these action method in your controller.

```
    public ActionResult MyView()
    {
        return PartialView("MyView");
    }
```

and then in your view add actionlink

```
    @Html.ActionLink("MyView", "MyView")
```

Now you can see your new partial view.